# How to copy the terminal's output and paste them into input?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

Does anyone know the function that I have to use to copy the output in the terminal?

For example, in terminal, if I input "ls", it gives me a list of files. I want to copy some of the texts and paste them into the next command to do "cd ". Is shell script able to do that?

Comment: Elaborate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ls | pbcopy` to get a list of the files (file names) copied to the clipboard (mac/unix).

To copy the contents of the text files, you can use `cat`:

```
cat filename.txt | pbcopy
```

Definition of the `|` character http://www.linfo.org/vertical_bar_character.html

Comment: is it possible to use regex or some kind of other means to filter out only the file that I want?

Answer (score 3):

You sound quite unfamiliar with `bash`, so here are a few hints about selecting files with wildcards, and regexes.

---

List files beginning with `a`

```
ls a*
```

---

List files beginning with `a` or `c`:

```
ls [ac]*
```

---

List files beginning with `a`, `b` or `c`:

```
ls [a-c]*
```

---

List files beginning with `a-l` or `n-z` but  not those starting with `m`:

```
ls [a-ln-z]*
```

---

List all files except those starting with `m` or a capital letter:

```
ls [^mA-Z]*
```

---

List `PNG` or `JPG` images:

```
ls *{png,jpg}
```

---

List PNG images with exactly 3 character/digit names:

```
ls ???.png
```

---

Another tip... this is an alternative to copying and pasting. Practice selecting files with `ls` as above (because `ls` is harmless), and when you have the correct regex, you can use `!$` in the next command to repeat it (the last *word* of the previous command) without re-typing. So, practice your regex till it looks good, e.g. select evenly numbered `PNG` images:

```
ls *{0,2,4,6,8}.png
```

Then, get a long listing of just those files:

```
ls -l !$
```